# Deploying a python package to AWS Lambda via Cloudformation, CodeBuild and CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I want to setup a CI/CD pipeline for my AWS infrastructure and a AWS Lambda function. The idea is to have everything in code, version-controlled and automated. I just want to `git push` to a repository and have CodePipeline take over from there, updating my infrastructure, running tests and, if successful, updating my Lambda function with the latest code.

I'm basing my CloudFormation template on [this excellent example](https://github.com/widdix/aws-velocity/blob/master/deploy/pipeline.yml). It looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: playground pipeline 1
Parameters:
  SourceRepositoryName:
    Type: String
    Default: lambda-playground
  SourceBranchName:
    Type: String
    Default: master

Resources:
  ArtifactsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: CloudFormationRole
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      BucketName: lambda-playground-artifacts

  CodeBuildRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DependsOn: CloudFormationRole
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codebuild.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ServiceRole
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Sid: CloudWatchWriteLogsPolicy
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: '*'
              - Sid: CodeCommitPullPolicy
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codecommit:GitPull
                Resource: '*'
              - Sid: S3GetObjectPolicy
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectVersion
                Resource: '*'
              - Sid: S3PutObjectPolicy
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                Resource: '*'

  CodePipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DependsOn: CloudFormationRole
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess

  CloudFormationRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service:
                - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess

  CodeCommitRepository:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: !Ref SourceRepositoryName

  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    DependsOn: CloudFormationRole
    Properties:
      Description: A playground of Lambda
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/python:2.7.12
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      Name: lambda-playground
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildRole.Arn
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      TimeoutInMinutes: 5

  CodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
      Name: !Ref AWS::StackName
      RestartExecutionOnUpdate: true
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: Source
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeCommit
                Version: 1
              Configuration:
                RepositoryName: !Ref SourceRepositoryName
                BranchName: !Ref SourceBranchName
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
        - Name: PipelineDeploy
          Actions:
            - Name: UpdatePipeline
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: 1
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
                StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
                TemplatePath: SourceOutput::infra.yml
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: BuildAndTest
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeBuild
                Version: 1
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildProject
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref BuildOutput # DOES NOT WORK
      FunctionName: playground-fc
      Handler: src.main.handler
      # TODO: Role: foo
      Runtime: python2.7

Outputs:
  ArtifactsBucketURL:
    Description: Artifacts bucket URL
    Value: !GetAtt ArtifactsBucket.WebsiteURL
  RepositoryURL:
    Description: SSH URL of the repository
    Value: !GetAtt CodeCommitRepository.CloneUrlSsh
```

So I have a CodePipeline with 3 stages - `Source`, which grabs code from a CodeCommit repo, `PipelineDeploy`, which updates my CloudFormation stack if necessary and `Build`, which runs the configured CodeBuild project.

My buildspec.yml is here:

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - python lib/pytest.py src
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - src/**/*
    - lib/**/*
```

It just installs the necessary libraries, runs the tests via pytest and creates a deployment zip. This zip file is then the `OutputArtifact` of the `Build` stage and gets stored in the `ArtifactsBucket`. However, each time, it gets a unique name (e.g. `dfVV6Uh`), which makes sense, but I don't know how to reference it in the LambdaFunction -> Properties -> Code -> S3Key field.

So my question is, how can I create a stack/pipeline, that after doing all the steps, will deploy the latest version to my AWS Lambda function? Is there a way to maybe use CodeDeploy to do this? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`Parameter Override`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html) with [`Fn::GetArtifactAtt`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html#d0e10247) and the `ObjectKey` attribute to dynamically provide the the name of the artifact `.zip` generated by AWS CodePipeline to your CloudFormation deploy action.

Using your example, the configuration for your `UpdatePipeline` CloudFormation deploy action would look something like this:

```
Configuration:
  ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
  Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
  RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
  StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
  TemplatePath: SourceOutput::infra.yml
  ParameterOverrides:
    {
      "LambdaKey" : { "Fn::GetArtifactAtt" : ["LambdaFunctionSource", "ObjectKey"]}
    }
InputArtifacts:
- Name: SourceOutput
- Name: BuildOutput
```

Then, declare and then reference the `LambdaKey` Parameter within your CloudFormation stack template:

```
Parameters:
  LambdaKey:
    Type: String
  # ...
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref LambdaKey
      # ...
```

Comment: So the idea is to have teh AWS::Lambda::Function declared in a separate CloudFormation template? Originally, I thought of having everything in one template, that's why the `UpdatePipeline` (a misleading name, now I realize) step is second in my pipeline. My Lambda function code is the output of the CodeBuild step, third one in the pipeline, so I guess I can't reference it in the second step (I haven't tried yet).

Comment: I based my answer on the template you provided in your question, which referenced `SourceOutput::infra.yml`. It's possible to set the template in your source repo as the same template you use to define your Code Pipeline resource, to make it self-referencing. See my repo at https://github.com/wjordan/aws-starter-kit for an fully self-contained example using GitHub.

Comment: I studied your aws-starter-kit and also attempted to modify my template based on your advice, but wasn't successful. The problem is I want to have everything in one template so I can bootstrap my infrastructure and update it continuously. To do that, when creating the Lambda function resource, I don't have the S3Key yet, that comes only as an output of my thirds pipeline step - the Build action. I guess I'll just create a dummy deployment package for the bootstrap step.

Comment: Took me a while to realize, but you were right. I'm quite new to CFN, I wasn't sure what the best practice is, but I've now split my infrastructure to two templates - on for the pipeline and one for the lambda function. I've added another deploy step to the pipeline using the way you suggested and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I now created [a repo](http://github.com/milancermak/lambda-pipeline) with the whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to do achieve something similar (deploying lambda functions via CodePipeline/CodeBuild).
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html

This example is for lambda functions written in NodeJS, but the basic idea is the same. You use CloudFormation to deploy/update your lambda functions after you've build your artifact via CodeBuild and let CodePipeline manage artifact propagation within stages.

Let me know if this helps.